# Item has been modified by other user

Tags: 2013, workflow, edit-form

We have some workflows that run on item creation and edit of item. They copy some information into other lists or update a notification.

When a workflow is added to a list it adds a "workflow status" column to the list. And as the workflow goes through its stages it updates the information in that status.

Unfortunately if a user opens the edit form while the workflow is running the contents of the status column will be updated as the workflow progresses and then when the user clicks save they will get a message that the item has been updated by another user and they can't update it.

Ironically the ​"other user" will usually be the same person -- because they just made the item and now they are editing it. Or the edited it, forgot one thing and went back in to update it again.

Is there some way to prevent this from happening? I've search the web, but the combination of "workflow and update and edit" point to a lot of other things.

Is there some way to prevent opening the edit form if the workflow is still running? Is there someway to let the workflow be less intrusive?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are running into data contention and SharePoint is saying the 1st change wins.

Option 1: You could lock the form by adding a check box field called "lock". default to true. Hide the field using JavaScript and onLoad of the edit form check if true. If true disable the save buttons. Then have the workflow set the field to false. This will only work for new.

Option 2: Eliminate the workflow. On the new/edit form use JavaScript to update the other list item when user clicks save. For the notification (assuming you mean email), I would use [SP.Utilities.Utility](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Working-With:-SP.Utilities.Utility) (more JavaScript). Good luck